# Raspberry Pi 2 with 2 or more HDD

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, hard-drive

I want to connect more than one 2,5" Hard Drive Disk to my Raspberry Pi 2.

1. The first question is, should it work ?
2. The second question is, which of these is the more efficient/stable solution :

   - Self powered HDD
   - USB Y cable connected to HDD and power source
   - Self powered HUB

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should work, the Pi2 has four USB ports so will support at least four USB devices.

No one can answer the second part of your question.  We have no idea of the relative quality, reliability, power consumption etc. etc., of the devices you might purchase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the second part we can imagine good quality and reliability of the devices and average consomption. In other words, with same number of devices connected should a self powered hub setup comsume more than devices connected with usb Y cable to a power source (the same that power supply the RPi) ?

Comment: @BDR terms like good quality and average consumption don't help they are nebulous. To provide an answer we require specific part numbers and product details.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Specific part number of what ? If connect a hard drive disk on a RPi either with a Y cable (and power source) or a Hub, the disk will consume the same amount of power, correct me if I am wrong. I just want to know what is the best solution.

If you really want part number : (disk : HGST Travelstar 5K1500 2.5", Y cable : Ugreen USB 3.0 1.5m, hub : LogiLink UA0125 Hub, Power source : RAVPower iSmart 4 ports Wall Charger)